# I keep getting stuck at authorize using xero-php-oauth2-app-master

Tags: xero-api

Please help!

I have been using the oauth2-app example code for a while and making slow and steady progress in the Demo Company.
Recently, if I am logged out when I renter I do not have the option to to continue with the Demo Company (indicates **already connected**) and my only option is connect with the Actual company. I want to continue working/testing the callback functionality. The only way I can do that is by removing APP in Xero Setting then reconnect, which is tiresome and I am sure the incorrect way.

Please can you tell me what needs to be changed so as I continue from the https://authorize.xero.com/ page.

Many Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to continue without selecting another organisation by clicking the "Allow Access" button without selecting more organisations.

If you've not connected any organisations, you'll need to choose an organisation to connect before allowing access. If you've already connected some organisations, you can choose to just continue with the orgs you've connected or connect more organisations.

Comment: Thanks; but that's my problem; how do I  "continue" there is no options/buttons for that only allow access and cancel?

Comment: Allow access can be clicked without selecting more organisations to connect